# My custom directive is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is my code:
I expect it to generate a div with a `<textarea>` or an `<ul>` following the `scope.current.type` from DB and set the `scope.current.content` in them.

But it doesn't work , on my page just simply show `<contentDirective></contentDirective>`

```
 app.directive("contentDirective", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: "<div class='new__content__input new__content__input-text'></div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (scope.current.type === 'Text') {
                var DOM = "<textarea>" + scope.current.content + "</textarea>";
                element.append(node);
            } else if (scope.current.type === 'Quote') {
                var DOM = "<textarea>" + scope.current.content + "</textarea>";
                element.append(node);

            } else if (scope.current.type === 'List') {

                var ul = "<ul>";
                for (var i = 0; i < scope.current.content.length; i++) {
                    ul += "<li>" + scope.current.content[i] + "</li>";
                }
                ul += "</ul>";
                element.append(ul);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

And my html :

```
<li ng-repeat="doc in who_u_r" ng-init=" current = doc " class="new__content__input__single clearfix">
    <contentDirective></contentDirective>
<li>
```

Thank you very much for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to This, Angular converts camelCasing to snake-casing,In this case, the name must be written using dashes and each dash represents a capital letter from the directive definition.

```
<content-directive></content-directive>
```

Comment: It works, thank you! Do you have time to explain it?

Comment: It's pretty straight forward, the directives created by Angular are camel-cased in Javascript because you can't use hyphens in names. In HTML, to keep with readability, they become separated by spaces. So `myCustomDirective` in Javascript would become `<my-custom-directive></my-custom-directive>`

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems that I still have lot to work on.